# Is const_cast on "this" pointer an undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, this, undefined-behavior, const-cast

I have got the following c++ code. I can compile it with g++ 4.9.2 on Linux machine. Then when I run it, it prints 10. It seems that a new object is created and assigned to the pointer created using const_cast in the default constructor. There are no memory leaks (which I checked using valgrind). Is this some kind of an undefined behavior or is it legal?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
   public:
      A() : x(0)
      {
         A *tmp = const_cast<A*>(this);
         *tmp = A(10);
      }

      A(int x)
      {
         this->x = x;
      }

      int getX() const
      {
         return x;
      }

   private:
      int x;
};

int main()
{
   A a;

   cout << a.getX() << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `this` shouldn't be const in the constructor so the const-cast does nothing.

Comment: "There are no memory leaks" - I would hope not, since there isn't a single dynamic allocation in this entire source. Regardless, dare I ask why you want to `const_fast` a `this` in the *constructor* ?

Comment: The `const_cast` has nothing to do with it. You could just do `*this = A(10)`. Or `x = 10` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`const_cast` has nothing to do with the behavior you experience. Your code may be simplified to the following:

```
  A() : x(0)
  {
     *this = A(10);
  }
```

So, here the following happens if we want to create an object using a default constructor:

1. *before constructor body* Memory for the object `this` is reserved.
2. *x(0)* `0` is assigned to the member `x` of `this`.
3. *A(10)* A new (unnamed) object of class `A` is created using the constructor `A(int)`. This new object member `x` has value `10`.
4. *this=* Here the unnamed object is assigned (using the automatically generated copy assignment operator, which is field-wise) to `*this`. Thus, value of member `x` of `this` becames `10`.
5. *after that line* The temporary unnamed object is destroyed.
6. `this` is returned.

This is perfectly legal and expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks for explanation